# fullPage.js and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

I'm trying to use https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js in an underscores.me wordpress theme. I'm only an amateur programmer, so I might be missing something basic, but I just can't find out where I'm going wrong. I'd really appreciate anyone's help.

I've made only minimal modifications thus far to the underscores base theme, just trying to get the fullPage.js script working. Here's the project: http://www.loveroots.us

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in your code, check the javascript console and you will see the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Also, you are importing the scripts twice, at your `head` and at the bottom of your site. Do it only once, at the `head`.

Also jQueryUI should be added before fullpage.js.

### Update 2021:

fullPage.js now is available for [Elementor](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/wordpress-plugin-elementor/) and [Gutenberg](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/wordpress-plugin-gutenberg/) builders and soon for [Divi](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/wordpress-plugin-divi/) too.

However, if you want to install this by yourself you can check [this tutorial](https://isotropic.co/adding-fullpage-js-to-elementor-no-plugin/) too. Just note that fullPage.js support won't be provided for it and that fulPage.js extensions might not work on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I got the script initialized. The first slide shows correctly, but am unable to move to the following slide/s. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should check your code and figure it out by yourself, the problem is not with fullpage.js as you can see in this reproduction of your page: http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1/